# Div won't touch the very edge of screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this div "maindiv" touch both sides of the screen, or stretch to touch them both. I've looked up how to and I'm not getting anything specific.

I'm just trying to get it stretched to both side of the screen without creating a scrolling bar at the bottom!

```css
    body {
        background-image: url("https://i.gyazo.com/b31293b75dbdff3868a22fc90f9d465c.jpg");
     background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .header {
        min-height: 500px; 
    }

    .header p {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: 250px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        color: #f5dabf;
        font-size: 40px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 100;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        word-spacing: 20px;
        border-bottom: #f5dabf solid 1px;
        width: 25%;
        margin: auto;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }


    .maindiv {
       background-color: #ffffffe8;
       min-height: 250px;
       max-width: 100%;
       margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
      }

    .maindiv p {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      padding: 30px;
   
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="header"> <p> Infinite Design </p></div>

    <div class="maindiv">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed venenatis enim, ac auctor massa. Praesent eget libero sapien. Nulla facilisi. Proin id nunc diam. Aliquam efficitur consequat mauris. Donec vitae risus mollis, lobortis erat vitae, ultrices leo. Praesent rutrum mi non tellus malesuada, non mollis lacus blandit. Nullam ac tincidunt lacus. Integer maximus massa scelerisque placerat lacinia. Curabitur fermentum condimentum euismod. Nunc eu condimentum nunc. In vel viverra dolor. Cras vel ex molestie, gravida est et, ullamcorper sapien. Cras sapien leo, suscipit non tortor eu, hendrerit efficitur massa. Morbi ultricies hendrerit imperdiet.
    <br><br>
    Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla porttitor, elit quis eleifend dignissim, massa nunc dictum lorem, quis volutpat ex metus non urna. Morbi in vestibulum sapien. Phasellus massa dui, convallis eget consectetur non, aliquam sed ligula. Aliquam nec mauris tempor, laoreet lectus ut, gravida tortor. Aenean tempus hendrerit consequat. Nullam feugiat diam ut tortor congue, non consequat nulla consectetur. Integer eu consequat magna. Nunc placerat lacinia accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat.
    <br><br>
    </p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reset your margin and padding. Try this code.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may add `margin:0;` to the body tag.

As in default, html will add a margin to your `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
html, body { 
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```